# Using Real-Time Data to Dynamically Adjust Edge "costs" in OSMnx?

Tags: python, gps, gis, networkx, osmnx

My question is largely summarized in the title. I'm wondering if it's possible to weight the specific "edges" of a network by using real-time data feeds in an effort to create a more accurate "time to destination" estimate. If not with OSMnx, how would you suggest doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wondering if it's possible to weight the specific "edges" of a network by using real-time data feeds

Yes. You'll want to update the edge weights (e.g., `length`, or `travel_time`, or your own concoction) by [setting](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_edge_attributes.html) those edge attributes. You can do this whenever you like, and then (re-)calculate shortest paths using that weight attribute accordingly.